# Generating dynamic route upon form submission with MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm wondering how to generate a new AngularJS (1.x) route upon submission of a form. In a nutshell, I'm building an event creation app similar to Facebook events (fill out form fields > submit form > have a new Event route that anyone can access.)

I'm 99% sure it involves Angular's [$RouteProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), but can't seem to find the next step of the process from Googling around. Here's a pic of the form (a few bits may be added, like an event photo.)

[image: form field]

Essentially I need to be able to:

1. fill out event details
2. click Create Event button
3. generate new route with form field info populated inside that route
4. write this new data to MongoDB via Mongoose

Any reference to tutorials or general direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a very complex question as it wraps a lot of different issues, back and frontend-wise.

I'm assuming you know how to send data to your backend engine. So this is basically what you need (to read):

Refs:

(AngularJS Routing)
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

(AngularJS Route params)
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

(Creating an API in NodeJS)
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

(Saving data to MongoDB)
http://www.jenniferbland.com/saving-data-to-mongodb-database-from-node-js-application-tutorial/
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

I highly recommend that you use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to simplify http requests from AngularJS to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new route when your application is already loaded, because the routes are created in config time. But, you can create a dynamic route.

So, with a dynamic route:

yoursite.com/events/**idEvent** -> idEvent is your dynamic path

I suggest you to use **ui-router**, because it is more complete and powerful:
 [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference)

So, with ui-router:

1 - Register your dynamic route with ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
  url: '/app'
  //here you can have a lot of configurations
  );

$stateProvider.state('app.event', {
  url: '/event/{idEvent}',
  //other configurations like controller, resolver, etc
})
```

2 - You can redirect the user to an specific event using:

```
//You need to inject $state in your controller
$state.go('app.event', {idEvent: 1});
//This line will redirect the user to the event page with idEvent 1
```

3 - To access your id inside your controller, you can use: [stateParams service](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service)

```
controller: function($stateParams){
   console.log($stateParams.idEvent);
}
```

To use this approach, be sure that you inject all modules needed to use ui-router.

This may be your flow:

1. fill out event details
2. click Create Event button
3. write this new data to MongoDB via Mongoose
4. redirect the user to the dynamic page, loading the content for that specific event

Note that the controller and template of the event page should be able to deal with loading dynamic content. So, build your controller making it possible to load content dynamically.

You can see this docs too: [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router)

Simple explanation: [AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

You will find a lot of sites showing how to configure and build routes using ui-router.